# Android - Ignition library - unbound class path variable error

Tags: android, maven

So I donwloaded the [ignition library](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition), built with Maven and imported as a project into eclipse.

However, all the libraries and sample code have a red exclamation mark in front of project name, and they do not compile. The "Problems" console shows that there are some problems with Build Path, and there are a lot of "**Unbound classpath variable: 'M2_REPO'...**" entries.
I see they point to some jar files.

Please tell me how can I get rid of these errors and fix the projects so they compile?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a classpath variable `M2_REPO` to your project:

[image]

It looks like your use classic way import project into workspace (File -> Import ... -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace), if I recall, this is the reason why Eclipse asking for a fixed-name classpath varlable `M2_REPO`.

If the Android project is properly mavenized, you should install two Eclipse plugins (m2e & m2e-android) and import project as a maven project (File -> Import ... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects), this does not require classpath vaiable `M2_REPO`.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: After doing this, you will probably need to run mvn eclipse:clean and eclipse:eclipse in the project directory to rebuild the Eclipse-specific files (.settings, .classpath, .project) and refresh the project files in Eclipse before trying to build in Eclipse again.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can add M2_REPO classpath variable via Maven command “eclipse:configure-workspace“

```
mvn -Declipse.workspace="your Eclipse Workspace" eclipse:configure-workspace
```